# Load Drop Down Selection Dynamically via Ajax PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, forms, drop-down-menu

I have a form that is currently online and functioning - I spent most of yesterday searching for and implementing an AJAX solution for my FIRST set of drop-down boxes.  But I want to add an additional set of three drop-down selection boxes to the form.  The first two are no big deal.  They have already been added to the form and are dynamically generated from two MYSQL tables at the initial loading of the form.

However, the third drop-down is proving to be a bit more tricky.

I have one set of drop-downs already on the form, which are dynamically generated in a multi-step process (ie. selection of first drop-down then loads list in second drop-down via AJAX, selection of second drop-down then loads list in the third drop-down dynamically via AJAX based on that input.

This works well.  However, I didn't write the code and can't fully work through the details of how it works.  I understand the php pretty well, but the AJAX stuff has me baffled, and that's the part I need to understand for the new drop-downs.

In this new group of drop-downs, the second list doesn't depend upon the first.  Both the first and second lists load at page load.  It is only the third drop-down which must be loaded via AJAX, but, in this case, it is dependent upon BOTH the first and second selection choices.

So, in other words, the user makes the first selection and then makes the second (which is NOT dependent upon the first).  But, upon making that second selection, the third drop-down is AJAX populated based on the selections made for BOTH the first and second list.

I have no idea how to do this.

I'm including my current code below.  It's a little lengthy, but I don't know if it's possible to build off the already present AJAX and PHP functions in order to minimize the new code.  In addition, I don't know if any new code might conflict with the old, so it's provided below.

I know this is a relatively tall order (at least it seems like it to me), but I really need this form completed, and I've been working on this implementation all day and can't seem to understand the AJAX code well enough to complete it myself.

Here's my current code (without alot of the extra formatting code):

```
<?php
   $dbh = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
      or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
   $selected = mysql_select_db("evaluate_motoroilevaluator",$dbh);
   if( isset($_GET['ajax']) )
   {
      //In this if statement
      switch($_GET['ID'])
      {
         case "LBox2":
            $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM vehicle_data_makes WHERE List1Ref=%d",$_GET['ajax']);
         break;
         case "LBox3":
            $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM vehicle_data_all WHERE List2Ref=%d",$_GET['ajax']);

         break;
      }

      $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
      {
         echo "<option value='{$row['ID']}'>{$row['Name']}</option>\n";
      }
      mysql_close($dbh);
      exit; //we're finished so exit..
   }

   if (!$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vehicle_data_years"))
   {
      echo "Database is down";
   }
   //for use with my FIRST list box
   $List1 = "";
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
   {
      $List1 .= "<option value='{$row['ID']}'>{$row['Name']}</option>\n";
   }
?>





<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script language="javascript">
   function ajaxFunction(ID, Param)
   {
      //link to the PHP file your getting the data from
      //var loaderphp = "register.php";
      //i have link to this file
      var loaderphp = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>";

      //we don't need to change anymore of this script
      var xmlHttp;
      try
       {
         // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
         xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
       }catch(e){
         // Internet Explorer
         try
         {
            xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
         }catch(e){
            try
            {
               xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }catch(e){
               alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
               return false;
            }
         }
      }

      xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
         if(xmlHttp.readyState==4)
           {
              //the line below reset the third list box incase list 1 is changed
                var sSelect = document.getElementById(ID);
                for(options in sSelect.options) sSelect.remove(options);
                var opt = document.createElement("option");
                sSelect.options.add(opt);
                var data = xmlHttp.responseText;

                results = data.split('\n');
                for(r in results){
                    var d =  results[r];
                    match = d.match(/<option value='(.*?)'>([^<]*)<\/option>/);
                    if (match != null) {
                        var opt = document.createElement("option");
                        opt.value= match[1];
                        opt.text = match[2];
                        sSelect.options.add(opt);
                    }
                }
           }
      }
       xmlHttp.open("GET", loaderphp+"?ID="+ID+"&ajax="+Param,true);
       xmlHttp.send(null);
   }
</script>
</head>
<body>







<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action ="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" name="myForm" accept-charset="utf-8">

    <ul class="form-section">
      <li id="cid_1" class="form-input-wide">
        <div class="form-header-group">
          <h1 id="header_1" class="form-header">
            Enter Vehicle Info
          </h1>
          <div id="subHeader_1" class="form-subHeader">
            Tell us about your vehicle
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="form-line" id="id_3">
        <label class="form-label-left" id="label_3" for="input_3"> Vehicle Model Year<span class="form-required">*</span> </label>
        <div id="cid_3" class="form-input">
         <select class="form-dropdown" style="width:150px" name="list1" id="LBox1" onchange="ajaxFunction('LBox2', this.value);">
         <option value=''></option>
      <?php 
         echo $List1;
      ?>
         </select>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="form-line" id="id_4">
        <label class="form-label-left" id="label_4" for="input_4"> Vehicle Make<span class="form-required">*</span> </label>
        <div id="cid_4" class="form-input">
          <select class="form-dropdown" style="width:150px" name="list2" id="LBox2" onchange="ajaxFunction('LBox3', this.value);">
         <option value=''>  </option>
            <!-- OK the ID of this list box is LBox2 as refered to above -->
          </select> (allow time to load following above selection)
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="form-line" id="id_5">
        <label class="form-label-left" id="label_5" for="input_5"> Vehicle Model<span class="form-required">*</span> </label>
        <div id="cid_5" class="form-input">
         <select class="form-dropdown" style="width:150px" name="list3" id="LBox3">
         <option value=''>  </option>
            <!-- OK the ID of this list box is LBox3 Same as above -->
         </select> (allow time to load following above selection)
        </div>
      </li>



<!-- ----------------------NEW STUFF ----------------------------- -->      

<?php 

   //for use with my FIRST motor oil drop-down: viscosity
   $Viscosity_List = "";
   $vis_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM viscosity");
   while ($vis_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($vis_result))
   {
      $Viscosity_List .= "<option value='{$vis_row['id']}'>{$vis_row['name']}</option>\n";
   }

?>

<?php 

   //for use with my SECOND motor oil drop-down: Brand
   $Brand_List = "";
   $brand_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM oil_brand ORDER BY brandname");
 //  $brand_result = asort($brand_result);
   while ($brand_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($brand_result))
   {
      $Brand_List .= "<option value='{$brand_row['brandid']}'>{$brand_row['brandname']}</option>\n";
   }

?>






      <li class="form-line" id="id_12">
        <label class="form-label-left" id="label_12" for="input_12">
          Motor Oil Viscosity<span class="form-required">*</span>
        </label>
        <div id="cid_12" class="form-input">
          <select class="form-dropdown validate[required]" style="width:150px" id="input_12" name="oil_viscosity">
            <option>  </option>
      <?php 
         echo $Viscosity_List;
      ?>
          </select>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="form-line" id="id_13">
        <label class="form-label-left" id="label_13" for="input_13">
          Motor Oil Brand<span class="form-required">*</span>
        </label>
        <div id="cid_13" class="form-input">
          <select class="form-dropdown validate[required]" style="width:150px" id="input_13" name="oil_brand">
            <option>  </option>
      <?php 
         echo $Brand_List;
      ?>
          </select>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="form-line" id="id_14">
        <label class="form-label-left" id="label_14" for="input_14">
          Motor Oil Product<span class="form-required">*</span>
        </label>
        <div id="cid_14" class="form-input">
          <select class="form-dropdown validate[required]" style="width:150px" id="input_14" name="oil_product">
            <option>  </option>
            <option value="Option 1"> Option 1 </option>
            <option value="Option 2"> Option 2 </option>
            <option value="Option 3"> Option 3 </option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </li>




<!-- -------------------------------- END NEw STUFF ------------------------------- -->




        <li class="form-line" id="id_2">

            <button id="input_2" type="submit" class="form-submit-button">
              Submit Form
            </button>

      </li>
      </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Many thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, with some continued searching, I finally found my answer in a script that was posted here:

http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/01/populate-triple-drop-down-list-change-options-value-from-database-using-ajax-and-php.html

It wasn't EXACTLY what I needed, but it was awfully close, and a few modifications did exactly what I needed done.  Either create your tables based upon the values in the script, or, if your tables already exist, as in my case, just be careful how you edit/rename all of the variable/table/column names in the script and it will do a terrific job.

In my case, although I didn't really need a "three step" drop down (and my database tables structure didn't provide the means for it), I used the script pretty much as is, but I removed the "where" clause from the mysql query within the findState.php file, thus listing ALL entries from that table instead of only ones that matched the ID from the first selection box.

Hopefully, if you download the files from the link above and open them up, the explanation above will be more clear.

Sorry I can't explain all the programming.  I'm not a programmer and don't always FULLY understand all the code, but I'm pretty good at taking scripts other people have written and modifying them for my own purposes.

Feel free to ask questions, if need be.  I'll try to answer as best I can.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first thing I noticed is that the you missed checking the status for the "onstatechange" function.  The following should be added to the readyState check:  `&& status == 200`

The second thing is don't get snarled in the logic.

The first drop down can or cannot be modified by the user -- therefore it doesn't affect the other two drop downs.

The second drop down affects the third therefore is the "parent" of sorts.

The third drop down gets its cue from the second and should be loaded using ajax.

Your PHP looks ok, I didn't see anything glaring.  So it seems that your problem is related to Javascript.

Think of of the web page as a series of nested nodes.  The grandparent of all nodes is "document".  You can find any HTML node within document by its "id" attribute like this:

```
document.getElementById("node-id-here");
```

To use this effectively you just do this:

```
var node = document.getElementById("someNode");
if(node != null)
{
   var list = myAjaxResponse;
   node.innerHTML = list;
}
```

This is a very basic example of how to use Javascript, there are many more comprehensive guides to Javascript.  Also once you learn Javascript, feel free to implement one of several different JS libraries, like jQuery, etc.

Good luck!

H

Comment: I appreciate your comments, and will probably be able to put them to use down the road, but I guess I'm just not clear enough on how to apply them to my current script.  Nevertheless, I am going to try and answer my own question below, as I found a script online that basically did exactly what I wanted (with a few slight modifications).  I'm going to post it in an answer below, but here's the link: [link]http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/01/populate-triple-drop-down-list-change-options-value-from-database-using-ajax-and-php.html[/link]